# In how many ways can 6 (distinct) persons be seated on 3 (alike) scooters (each scooter will carry EXACTLY 2 persons)?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

I have taken almost 100 minutes pondering over this problem.

Although I have arrived at the answer which is **15** but I am not able to figure out the correct approach to solve such kind of problems.

I want to know the systematic approach towards solving this type of problems as I know that manual method won't work in more complicated problems of such type.

Please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think about it as follows:

Line up all 6 people, and then have the first two go on scooter 1, the next two on scooter 2, and the last two on scooter 3.

Now, since the people are distinguishable, you have $6!$ possible line-ups, but this of course overcounts the number of scooter arrangements in two different ways:

1. First of all, the members of each pair can swap places (or at least it just wants to know what pair goes onto a scooter; it does not distinguish driver from passenger). So, for example, if you have line-up:

$$123456$$

then you can swap the people of the first pair:

$$213456$$

but still get the same scooter arrangement.

Likewise, you can swap the members of the second and third pair. So, you need to divide by $2\cdot 2 \cdot 2$.

Now, if you had triplets going onto a scooter (say, we had 9 people and 3 scooters), then we can rearrange the members of each triplet in $3!$ ways. Thus, in general you would divide by $k!$, with $k$ being the number of items going into a group (though again, this is only when the group is seen as a set, i.e. has no further ordering).

So, in this case you really need to divide by $2! \cdot 2! \cdot 2!$, but that is just $2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2$

2. Second, the 3 scooters are indistinguishable, so the pairs can swap places as well (as a pair). For example, if you first have line-up

$$123456$$

and you swap the first pair with the second pair, you get:

$$341256$$

but again that will lead to the very same scooter arrangement. So, swapping pairs does not change the scooter arrangement. Since we have 3 pairs (think of it as pair A, B, and C), we can rearrange those pairs in $3!$ ways.

Final answer:

$$\frac{6!}{2!2!2!3!} = 15$$

And as a general formula:

If you want to divide $n$ items into $m$ groups of size $k$, where the groups are indistinguishable, and where the items within the group are indistinguishable (or, as here, the group is seen as a set):

$$\frac{n!}{{k!}^m \cdot m!}$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your valuable answer.

Comment: Can you help me understand this

Comment: First of all, the members of each pair can swap places. So, you need to divide by 2!2!2!

Comment: Because I am totally a beginner in permutations and combinations

Comment: And also this -

Comment: Since there are 3!  to get those 3 pairs, you need to divide by 3!

Comment: @user134175 Take the first pair. They can swap places in the line-up, but they will still end up on the same scooter as a pair. So, you need to divide by $2$ for that first pair. The same goes for the second and third pair.  I made that into $2!$, since if you had triplets going onto a scooter, you would need to divide by the number of ways you can rearrange those 3 people, which is $3!$.  So I was aiming for a geneal formula here, since you asked for that.

Comment: It would be very very helpful of you... because I wasn't able to understand the concept involved here even when my teacher was teaching me

Comment: As far as the swapping of pairs goes.  What I mean: if you first have line-up 123456, and you swap the first pair with the second pair, you get 341256.  But that will lead to the very same scooter arrangement. So, swapping pairs does not change the scooter arrangement. Since we have 3 pairs (think of it as pair A, B, and C), we can rearrange those pairs in $3!$ ways.

Comment: Thank you very much @Bram28... Now I have totally understood this concept... Thank you again for clarifying my doubts :)

Comment: @user134175 Glad I could help! :)